# Knowing when to use a Double, String or Int when casting an Array from an API?

Tags: xcode

I am trying to cast multiple Arrays from a weather API. I was able to get the 5 day highs using a Double, then I was able to match them with the days of the week using a String.

Now I am trying to pull the the 5 days lows and the weather Icons associated to the day and no matter what I use Double, String or Int there is no data coming back.

Here is a part of my code that is working.

```
var temperatureArray: Array<Double> = Array()
var dateArray: Array<String> = Array()
var iconArray: Array<String> = Array()
var dayNumber = 0
var readingNumber = 0
if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data,   options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
    if let mainArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "list") as? NSArray {
        for dict in mainArray {
            if let mainDictionary = (dict as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "main") as? NSDictionary {
                if let temperature = mainDictionary.value(forKey: "temp_max") as? Double {


                    if readingNumber == 0 {
                        temperatureArray.append(temperature)
                    } else if temperature > temperatureArray[dayNumber] {
                        temperatureArray[dayNumber] = temperature

                    }

                } else {
                    print("Error: unable to find temperature in dictionary")
                }


                        if let date = (dict as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "dt_txt") as? String {

                            if readingNumber == 0 {
                                dateArray.append(date)   

                        }

                }

                    } else {
                        print("Error: unable to find main in dictionary")
                    }

            if let icon = (dict as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "icon") as? String {


                if readingNumber == 0 {
                    iconArray.append(icon)

            }
                }

                    readingNumber += 1
                    if readingNumber == 8 {
                        readingNumber = 0
                        dayNumber += 1        

    }

}
```

I get no build errors, but cannot draw data for the icon array.

Comment: Does the API have documents you can refer to? Do you have a link to share for us to refer to the API? Are you working with a debugger, so that you can set a break point and inspect what data types the underlying data consist of? Learning how to debug and how to read API documents are a necessary first step before asking people to do those tasks for you.

Comment: Do not use JSONSerialization any longer. Use Decodable.

Comment: The values for key `icon` are not in the dictionaries in the `list` array. **Read** the JSON, it's very simple: `[]` is `Array` (not `NSArray` in Swift), `{}` is `Dictionary` (not `NSDictionary` in Swift), everything in double quotes is `String`, numeric floating point values are `Double`, all others `Int`, `true / false` is Bool, `null` is `nil`. That's the entire type set of JSON.

Comment: @vadian, thank you for the input, but before I change the the NSDictionary and the NS Array, I am receiving all the data I need from the 5 day Temp highs and 5 day days of the week. That part is working great it is just adding more Arrays, I will take a closer look at the data, but I believe the Icon Array is a String.

Comment: @ Bane the data is coming from https://openweathermap.org/api

Comment: @ matt, in place of JSONSerialization? Are you saying just drop it into the existing code?

Comment: @vadian: even though you say icon is not in the list dictionary, this is not making sense?  {"cod":"200","message":0.0055,"cnt":40,"list":[{"dt":1524668400,"main":{"temp":8.21,"temp_min":7.14,"temp_max":8.21,"pressure":1007,"sea_level":1026.08,"grnd_level":1007,"humidity":100,"temp_kf":1.07},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}] and the "list" closing ] ends at the of the 5day.   The dictionary should be "weather" but xCode not let me cast as a Double. And as a String it builds but crashes on returning data and returns "iconArray [String] 0 values"

Comment: It does make sense, Once again *please **read** the JSON* carefully. The key `icon` is in a dictionary (other keys `id`, `main`, `description`) – note the braces `{}` – which is in array for key `weather` – note the brackets `[]` – . The `weather` object is in a dictionary which is in an array for key `list`. I know the openweathermap JSON format quite well.

Comment: So reading the data this must be a Double. If this is true then I can not get Xcode to return with this call "self.iconImage1.image = UIImage(named: iconArray [0])" Xcode is saying this is a String and I am getting this error: "Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'String'" This is where I need help....

Comment: @vadian, I am having no luck either way...Is this a String or a Double. I am pretty sure it is a String now. But this is the crash error I get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: You cannot create the image directly from the string `"10d"`. This is just a tiny path component of the URL. You have to concatenate `"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png"`, then create the URL and load the image (asynchronously). For example paste `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/10d.png` in your browser. `UIImage(named` is the wrong API anyway. The file is **not** in the application bundle.

Comment: Yes I know, and I have all the images in my Assets. On my Daily Weather View the Icons display no problem and change when updated. I bring the API in like this: self.iconImage.image = UIImage(named: weatherIcon). In the 5 day, what would bring in the API, I think that is the main issue I need to get around, any ideas?

Comment: @vadian "UIImage(named is the wrong API anyway. The file is not in the application bundle." Can you reply with the right one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vadian, thank you!! I took me a while, but we were actually trying to break though 2 Array Strings to get to the "icon" key!! this is how I did it.

if let mainArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "list") as? NSArray {
                        for dict in mainArray {

```
                        if let weatherArray = (dict as AnyObject).value(forKey: "weather") as? NSArray {
                            if let weatherDictionary = weatherArray[0] as? NSDictionary {
                                if let icon = weatherDictionary.value(forKey: "icon") as? String {
```